# Can we pass Model.item.value as a CSS class in Mvc3?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have one doubt: can we pass `Model.item.value` to a CSS class in MVC3?

For example:

```
@foreach (var items in Model)
{
    @Html.TextBox(@items.ShortDesc, @items.SfldDefault, new { @class = "@items.ShortDesc"})
}
```

I want to print my `@items.ShortDesc` as the CSS class but it's taking it as a string here.. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to write it without the quotation marks and `@` symbol (no need for those, as you're already inside a code block):

```
@Html.TextBox(items.ShortDesc, items.SfldDefault, new { @class ="abc "+ items.ShortDesc })
```

Comment: if  i   need  to  write  with  class  then  like  @class="abc items.ShortDesc"  then  its  taking  as  a  string

Comment: yes  i  have  done  lit  changes  in your  code  now  its  working